# Restkit mapping arrays to core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit-0.20

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "editable": true,
    "number": "1",
    "name": "Text here",
    "banner": "Text here",
    "address": "Text here",
    "city": "Text here",
    "contact": "Text here",
    "latitude": "Text here",
    "longitude": "Text here",
    "banner_id": 5,
    "hours": [
        {
            "day": "monday",
            "start": "8:00am",
            "end": "5:00pm"
        },
        {
            "day": "tuesday",
            "start": "",
            "end": ""
        },
        {
            "day": "wednesday",
            "start": "",
            "end": ""
        },
        {
            "day": "thursday",
            "start": "",
            "end": ""
        },
        {
            "day": "friday",
            "start": "",
            "end": ""
        },
        {
            "day": "saturday",
            "start": "",
            "end": ""
        },
        {
            "day": "sunday",
            "start": "",
            "end": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to create a mapping of this object which contains an array of hours, my code is as follows:

```
RKObjectMapping* hoursMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Hours class] ];
    [hoursMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"day", @"start", @"end"]];

    RKObjectMapping* storeMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Store class] ];
    [storeMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"id", @"editable", @"number", @"name", @"banner", @"address", @"city", @"contact", @"latitude", @"longitude", @"banner_id"]];

    [storeMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"hours"
                                                                               toKeyPath:@"hours"
                                                                             withMapping:hoursMapping]];

    RKResponseDescriptor *storeResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:storeMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                   pathPattern:@"api/v2/stores.json"
                                                                                       keyPath:@""
                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

The mapping fails and the only error returned says:
"The operation couldn't be completed"

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get this to map successfully?

Store.h

```
@interface Store : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * editable;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * number;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * banner;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * city;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * contact;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * banner_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *hours;
@end

@interface Store (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addHoursObject:(Hours *)value;
- (void)removeHoursObject:(Hours *)value;
- (void)addHours:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeHours:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Hours.h

```
@interface Hours : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * day;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * start;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * end;

@end
```

Comment: Hi, Instead of addPropertyMapping try using :
   ' /** RKRelationshipMapping Store has array of Hour */
    [storeMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"hours" mapping:hourMapping]; ' your store ManagedObject should have the relation to hour managedObject in Model

Comment: @Idali Thank you for the reply. Now that I've done that I get the following error message: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Store'

Comment: you need to review your RestKit initialization, it not mappiing error

Comment: @Idali I have added these to the end of my question

Comment: by the way you should name your NsmanagedObject Hour instead of Hours,  keep "hours" to represent the relation in store.hours

Comment: Thanks for your help @idali! I have managed to solve this problem with your help. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to find a solution to this problem:

The problem was that I was using an Object Mapping with Core Data.
I changed all references to an Object Mapping into Entity Mappings instead. The relationship mapping is the same but now points to the Core Data entity instead of the class. Now everything works as expected.

```
RKEntityMapping *storeMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Store" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    storeMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];
    [storeMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"id", @"editable", @"number", @"name", @"banner", @"address", @"city", @"contact", @"latitude", @"longitude", @"banner_id"]];

    RKEntityMapping *hoursMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Hours" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [hoursMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"day", @"start", @"end"]];
    [storeMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"hours" toKeyPath:@"hours" withMapping:hoursMapping]];

    RKResponseDescriptor *storeResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:storeMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:@"/api/v2/stores.json"
                                                                                           keyPath:@""
                                                                                       statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];


    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:storeResponseDescriptor];
```

For more information visit: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/restkit-tutorial-how-to-fetch-data-from-an-api-into-core-data-9326af750e10